# Adding multiple records in SQL through nodeJS

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

I want to add multiple new records to my SQL table called 'absentteachers' through nodeJS with the condition the new record does not already exists.
I have no issues with connectivity to SQL or something. I just need help in what will be the SQL statement for the same.

Comment: Try looking here -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/548541/insert-ignore-vs-insert-on-duplicate-key-update

Comment: This also has nothing to do with node.js if all you need is the SQL.  Either way, though, all questions should include some demo of what you've tried already.